# Browsermob - Python - Windows Java process stay running after proxy.close and server.stop

Tags: python, windows, selenium, process, browsermob-proxy

I have a python - selenium - browsermob script which is waiting and listening a server for a task on standby inside a while loop until termination. When task is assigned, it calls a function which at each call creates new browsermob proxy server object and a selenium webdriver objects. After it does the work, I close the proxy with proxy.close() function, stop server by server.stop() function and quit web driver by driver.quit() function. But each time function is called, new process of java.exe starts to run and never stops, so after each function call my memory consumption increases significantly. Is there any way to terminate that already used java processes?

Answer (score 1):

If you work under Windows, this is still an open issue: [Server.stop() does not kill the java process in Windows](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py/issues/8).